# Perl regular expressions match at least but no more than

Tags: regex, perl

If "a{m,n} = at least m but at most n a’s", why does the code returns true?

```
  my $seq= "xxxx";
  print "bingo!" if ($seq =~ /x{2,3}/);
```

Since our n=3 and the string contains 4 x?
I guess I am having troubles with the definition of `/a{m,n}/` with respect to n. After all, the point was to make sure we have max 3 x in the string...or?
Can someone explain? 
 I am asking for the logics of having to specify a max of occurrences when it does not work like that. Meaning that I want to match maximum 3 and the string has 4; I get TRUE and I assume that the maximum is 3. When in fact it is 4.
Thanks.

Comment: With respect, I do not see the answer to my question in none of those 3 answers. I am asking for the logics of having to specify a max of occurrences when it does not work like that. Meaning that I want to match maximum 3 and the string has 4; I get TRUE and I assume that the maximum is 3. When in fact it is 4.

Comment: you are not matching the full string. `/^x{2,3}$/` would be false, whereas `/^x{2,4}$/` would be true. `/x{2,3}/` matches, `/^x{2,3}y/` would not even if you added a y to the end.

Comment: The first 2 characters of the strings are 'x' characters so the regex matches i.e.: there is at least one point in the string that is followed by 2 or 3 'x's. The fact that that point in the string is followed by even more 'x's is not prohibited by your regex.

Comment: I now understand. Thank you. I am sorry but from the original (suggested) post, I did not understand this very issue. Sorry for the duplicate but I had to find a way to understand.

Comment: another option is /x{2,3}[^x]/ , which means the next after the x{2,3} must not be x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl regexes are unanchored by default (this is not true of every regex implementation out there).  This means that if there's any substring of the input string that in your case has 2 or 3 x's, the match is successful.

```
my $seq= "xxxx";
print "bingo!" if ($seq =~ /^x{2,3}$/);
```

Will fail to match (the only strings it will match are "xx" and "xxx".

Alternatively:

```
my $seq= "xxxx";
print "bingo!" if ($seq =~ /([^x]|^)x{2,3}([^x]|$)/);
```

Would also fail to match, but would match any string that had 2 or 3 consecutive x's, but not if those x's were part of a longer string of x's.